# How to use TOTP / HOTP library in PHP

Tags: php, one-time-password

I tried to implement TOTP PHP library as another authentication for my login form. I downloaded and followed installation instruction from [github](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp) as folowing code:

```
<?php
include('src/Factory.php');
include('src/HOTP.php');
include('src/HOTPInterface.php');
include('src/OTP.php');
include('src/OTPInterface.php');
include('src/ParameterTrait.php');
include('src/TOTP.php');
include('src/TOTPInterface.php');
use OTPHP\TOTP;

$otp = TOTP::create();
echo 'The current OTP is: '.$otp->now();
?>
```

Yet, I ended up with error message `Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in C:\wamp64\www\otp\src\HOTP.php on line 3` and `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\otp\src\HOTP.php on line 28`.

I could not figure out why it was that. Very much appreciate for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you are using PHP7 feature in PHP5. Strict type is only supported on 7+.

Comment: my current version: PHP 5.6.25, so should I uninstall and upgrade to version 7?

Comment: Yup if you want to use that library. If you own that library I guess you can remove all PHP7 feature. But I won't recommend that. Upgrading would be a better solution for you I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install lower version of package like ~8.0, which works with PHP 5.5

https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp/blob/v8.3.2/composer.json#L19

add this in your composer.json

`"require": {
   "spomky-labs/otphp": "~8.3"
}`

Or use this link to download it as ZIP and add it to your project manually

https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp/archive/v8.3.2.zip

Better is to use composer, because you have auto autoloader. :) That way there is no need to manually require files.

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

try the multiOTP class, which is PHP 5.x compatible
https://github.com/multiOTP/multiotp